# How to change label pass field on registration form

Tags: forms

I need to change the password field label on the registration form. Name and Email I changed through hook_form_alter and password does not work. Help me!

```
$form['account']['name']['#title'] = 'Имя пользователя/Login';
$form['account']['mail']['#title'] = 'E-mail адрес/E-mail';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the soluition (need to clear the caches):

```
function MYMODULE_element_info_alter(&$type)
{
    // dpm($type);
    // assuming it's a password_confirm type
    $type['password_confirm']['#process'][] = 'custom_pass';
}

function custom_pass($element)
{
    $element['pass1']['#title'] = 'Пароль / Password';
    ...

    return $element;
}
```